# can anyone tell me if a class extends view than how can i can i call xml in it to show buttons at bottom of image

Tags: android

**THis is My MainActivity which Activity**

```
public class MainActvity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new BitmapView(this));
}
```

**I have To show an Xml File having some buttons at bottom of this image**

```
class BitmapView extends View {
    public BitmapView(Context context) {
        super(context);``
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I may be missing the context/limitations, but why not create an XML layout that has the bitmap as an image/background and buttons on the bottom of the screen? Then just inflate/create that layout instead of trying pull everything together in the code behind?

Comment: Actually This Image Comes from Gridview and at the bottom of this image i have to use 5  buttons from which diff diff activity are called....  also i have to move another image over this image .....called by one of the buttons....

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do so since the buttons won't be responsible (I mean, they won't be clickable nor change their state when they are pressed; in fact, it is up to you to detect when the buttons are pressed).

Whatever, if that's what you want, you can do so by doing something like this:

```
private void drawButton(Canvas canvas, float left, float right, Button button) {
    canvas.translate(left, right);
    button.draw(canvas);
    canvas.translate(-left, -right);
}
```

You can call this from within your onDraw method. Usually, you will have to instantiate the button manually. Also, you can draw entire Views... so, in that case you would have to either instantiate them or inflate them; then you just call its `draw` method passing the canvas you get on `onDraw`.

Comment: Actually This Image Comes from Gridview and at the bottom of this image i have to use 5  buttons from which diff diff activity are called....  also i have to move another image over this image .....called by one of the buttons....